# `backdrop-filter` does not work in headless mode?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit, headless

I am trying to apply the following `backdrop-filter` to the navigation bar. But it doesn't work at all in headless mode of all web browsers. When taking a screenshot of the web page in headless mode, the backdrop-filter never gets applied. It works fine in normal mode and I get the correct screenshot.

```css
nav {
    background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.75);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(150%) blur(30px);
    backdrop-filter: saturate(150%) blur(30px);
}
```

The strange thing is that this issue exists in all types of browsers that support headless browsing - be it Chrome, Firefox, or Webkit. I tested with latest versions.

Do anyone know why this happens and is there any workaround to make it work? I am not even looking for a cross-browser solution. Is this a known bug to be fixed by the browser developers?